# Click button and Side Menu slide out from hidden

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I want to make a similar navigation menu like what m.facebook.com did.
but this, i want to make it nicely animated slide out from left side of the website.

Flow ::
Click a button > (Menu is hidden by default) Menu Slide out, push the main container to right a bit to fit the menu > Click again > Menu Slide in and hidden again.

I got no idea to make it with javascript or jquery or ajax while i'm new to web development and there are too much of effect scripting language. May i know to achieve this, which is perfect in smoothness ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something along these lines... http://jsfiddle.net/HfdXY/

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">Menu</div>

<button id="openMenu">Toggle menu</button>​
```

CSS:

```
#menu {
    height: 300px;
    width: 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: none;
}​
```

JS:

```
$("#openMenu").click(function() {
    var menu = $("#menu");
    if ($(menu).is(":visible")) {
        $(menu).animate({width: 0}, 1000, function() {$(menu).hide();});
    } else {
        $(menu).show().animate({width: 100}, 1000);           
    }
});​
```

Comment: @lyrae Yes, this is by no means the best implementation.  It's just something I cobbled together quickly.  Take a look at the [jQuery documentation](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=jquery%20documentation&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.jquery.com%2F&ei=D4RMT4esNZH0sgag9sG5Dw&usg=AFQjCNHyeCiRC2DNX5kMMGuzvstY3mwu9w&sig2=_4m80VYsUABzDBoUEPFRwA). As documentations go it's a pretty good one.  You'll learn a lot.

Comment: @nickbrunt,  this is after editing but i can't make it hide out smoothly >.< additionally, if i want to make it into % instead of px for the width, possible ?? Thx http://jsfiddle.net/HfdXY/9/

Comment: @SLim You need to have the `hide()` function in a callback after `animate()` so that it hides once it has finished animating.  Otherwise it hides first and then animates (while you can't see it anyway).  Here's the fix: http://jsfiddle.net/HfdXY/14/

Comment: @NickBrunt, Finally =D Did it ^^ Thank you so much =D